# Generate Base64 from iTextSharp

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, base64, itext

I have the following method in my project.

```
        [Route("GerarPdf")]
        [HttpGet()]
        public object GerarPdf()
        {

            var doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
            var mem = new MemoryStream();

            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem);

            doc.Open();//Open Document to write
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("This is my first line using Paragraph.");
            Phrase pharse = new Phrase("This is my second line using Pharse.");
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk(" This is my third line using Chunk.");

            doc.Add(paragraph);
            doc.Add(pharse);
            doc.Add(chunk);

            var pdf = mem.ToArray();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(pdf);
        }
```

The objective of this code is generate a PDF file downloadable by the following JavaScript code

```
     var dataURI = "data:application/pdf;base64," +result;
     window.open(dataURI,'_blank');
```

But the new opened page return always a error on load PDF. The base64 code returned by the method to the result variable is:

```
JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MK
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you already try sending am existing Pdf doc obtained from a PdfReader? I use very similar code to yours to create email attachments, so it should be fine.

Comment: The PDF generation will not be static, the generation above is just a example. In the future I'll create a file totally personalized and the number of pages will be variable. So I believe that I couldn't use a static DOC from PdfReader.

Comment: I thought about verifying the javascript part - if it works for an existing doc, you can concentrate on analyzing the generated Pdf. You could also check the other way round and see if your generated Pdf opens from saved to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the doc was not closed in the moment of conversion to bytearray. After I added doc.Close(); the PDF was successfully generated.

```
        [Route("GerarPdf")]
        [HttpGet()]
        public object GerarPdf()
        {

            var doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
            var mem = new MemoryStream();

            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem);

            doc.Open();//Open Document to write
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("This is my first line using Paragraph.");
            Phrase pharse = new Phrase("This is my second line using Pharse.");
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk(" This is my third line using Chunk.");

            doc.Add(paragraph);
            doc.Add(pharse);
            doc.Add(chunk);

            doc.Close();

            var pdf = mem.ToArray();

            return Convert.ToBase64String(pdf);
        }
```

Comment: That's why I always put my docs and memory streams into a `using () { }` block that will close them automatically for me. If you are interested, I can post a modified version of your code.

Comment: You can post please.

Answer (score 1):

To have your `MemoryStream` and `Document` automatically closed + disposed for you, put them into `using()` blocks like this:

```
[Route("GerarPdf")]
[HttpGet()]
public object GerarPdf()
{
    byte[] pdf = new byte[] { };

    using (var mem = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35))
        {
            PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem);

            doc.Open(); //Open Document to write

            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("This is my first line using Paragraph.");
            Phrase pharse = new Phrase("This is my second line using Pharse.");
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk(" This is my third line using Chunk.");

            doc.Add(paragraph);
            doc.Add(pharse);
            doc.Add(chunk);
        } // doc goes out of scope and gets closed + disposed

        pdf = mem.ToArray();
    } // mem goes out of scope and gets disposed

    return Convert.ToBase64String(pdf);
}
```